# Query taking so long neo4j to merge relationships

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///relationships.tsv' as row
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
WITH row
MATCH (a:actor {id: row[2]}), (b:movie {id: row[0]}) MERGE (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(b)
```

Looks like this the file:

```
tt0015637   8   nm0166876   actor   \N  ["Bull Harding"]
tt2450056   2   nm0000616   actor   \N  ["Dr. Mc Millan"]
tt1053424   1   nm0000179   actor   \N  ["Remy"]
tt0062535   1   nm0176061   actor   \N  ["Ric"]
tt0016908   3   nm0384944   actor   \N  ["Capt. Blackwell"]
tt0020459   4   nm0176971   actor   \N  ["Pete"]
tt1300155   1   nm1497548   actor   \N  ["Moon Blake"]
```

row[0] is the id for the movie. row[2] is the id for the actor

Additionally, I also want row[3] to only be actor. Sometimes there is something like

```
tt0033839   5   nm0377613   director    \N  \N
```

I want row[3] to only be actor I tried

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///relationships.tsv' as row
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
WITH row
MATCH (a:actor {id: row[2]}), (b:movie {id: row[0]}) MERGE (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(b)
WHERE row[3] == 'actor'
```

But that gives me Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 5, column 2 (offset: 161))
"WHERE row[3] == 'actor'

I added all the actors who have properties name and id same with movie.

Why does this not work?

Comment: This: `==` is not a valid Cypher operator. Cypher uses `=` instead when doing equality when evaluating predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have indexes created on `:actor(id)` and `:movie(id)`.

And put `WHERE` statement after `WITH` statement, so first you will filter rows and then perform operations.